# How to use choice in Mule and to get value of variable "MULE_JDBC_UDATE_COUNT" back to client

Tags: mule

1. I'm trying to get my choice branch in Mule to branch on number of parameters in `http.query.params` is that possible?
2. How do I return the value of the `MULE_JDBC_UDATE_COUNT` variable to the client?

My config.xml

```
<spring:beans> 
    <spring:bean id="InformixDatasource" name="InformixDatasource" class="org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource"> 
        <spring:property name="password" value="xxxxx"></spring:property>  
        <spring:property name="driverName" value="com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver"></spring:property>  
        <spring:property name="user" value="informix"></spring:property>  
        <spring:property name="url" value="jdbc:informix-sqli://browning.frett.ehf:1527/dev:informixserver=ol_brown"></spring:property>  
    </spring:bean>  
</spring:beans>
<jdbc-ee:connector name="InformixConnector" dataSource-ref="InformixDatasource" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database"></jdbc-ee:connector>
<flow name="postdrefing_fetch_dataFlow1" doc:name="postdrefing_fetch_dataFlow1"> 
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="0.0.0.0" port="8084" doc:name="HTTP" path="postdreifing"></http:inbound-endpoint>  
    <logger message="before db Choice #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="message.inboundProperties['dreifing'] != null and message.inboundProperties['dags'] != null or message.inboundProperties['dags'] != null"> 
            <logger message="delete #[message.inboundProperties['http.query.params']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>  
            <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="deleteById" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="InformixConnector" doc:name="Delete from nafnadreifing by id"> 
                <jdbc-ee:query key="deleteById" value="DELETE FROM fdr_nafnadreifing WHERE dreifing = #[message.inboundProperties['dreifing']] and dags = TO_DATE(#[message.inboundProperties['dags']],'%d%m%Y')"></jdbc-ee:query>  
            </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>  
            <logger message="Deleted #[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UDATE_COUNT']] rows" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>
            <set-payload value="Deleted #[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UDATE_COUNT']] rows" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise> 
            <logger message="default" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"></logger>  
            <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="selectStatement" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="InformixConnector" doc:name="Select all from ibudaskra"> 
                <jdbc-ee:query key="selectStatement" value="SELECT skyring,gata,gata_thgf,husnumer,auka,pnr,hverfi,ibudafjoldi,fjolpostur,athugasemdir,breytt,bannmerki,uppfaert,sortnr,pakki,active,tegund,ibud FROM fdr_ibudaskra"></jdbc-ee:query>  
            </jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint>  
            <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"></json:object-to-json-transformer>  
        </otherwise>  
    </choice>  
</flow>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, this is possible, with something like `#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.params']['myQueryParamName']]`. Be sure to use `#[ ]` around your expression and also use '&&' and '||' for boolean operations.

   ```
   <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['dreifing'] != null &amp;&amp; message.inboundProperties['dags'] != null || message.inboundProperties['dags'] != null]">
   ```

   It also seems you're missing parenthesis around the part of this expression.
2. Use `set-payload`:

   ```
   <set-payload value="#[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UDPATE_COUNT']]" />
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply !

1.) I was hoping for something similar to this syntax

<when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.params'].numberOfParameters == 2]">

Because my Choice component will have to choice between three branches. No parameter invokes select statement. 2 parameters will invoke delete statement, and third a big object will invoke insert statement
2.)
This is not working, my reply to browser is "Deleted null rows". The variable "MULE_JDBC_UDATE_COUNT" is not created by me, I assume it's a part of the JDBC adapter and it appears under Variables in debug mode.

Comment: 1) Try with `message.inboundProperties['http.query.params'].size() == 2` 2) Typo maybe? Use `MULE_JDBC_UPDATE_COUNT` instead of `MULE_JDBC_UDATE_COUNT`.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Dossot
Number one: is working by my desire.
Number two: is not working, I assume the problem is that this variable is not a part of the message.inboundProperties scope ! What it returns is always null !

Comment: Oh, it's an invocation property variable, let me fix my answer.

Comment: Works like a charm :)
Thanks for your help, much a appreciated

Comment: I have one question about variable "MULE_JDBC_UDATE_COUNT"
Everything is working fine locally the variable returns the number of deleted rows. But when I upload my project to the Mule CE Server the variable starts to return value "null". I develop my projects first in EE edition so I can debug and other stuff, when I'm satisfied with my results I change the project back to CE edition and run it. If all is good, I upload the project to Mule CE Server.
any idea why this is happening ?
Would be much appreciated to figure this out !

Comment: The `MULE_JDBC_UDATE_COUNT` variable is a JDBC-EE only feature. If you deploy on CE, you should not use any EE feature at development time, for example, use the `jdbc` namespace instead of the `jdbc-ee` one.